# C# equivalent of C++ std::string find_first_not_of and find_last_not_of

Tags: c#, string

`IndexOf`, `IndexOfAny` and `LastIndexOf`, `LastIndexOfAny` dont seem to do these (or maybe they do). I'm looking for the equialent of std::string's `find_first_not_of` and `find_last_not_of`. I'm thinking about creating an extension class but I'm not sure if C# already provides this functionality.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
string source = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
string chars = "ogd hte";

int? firstNotOf = source.Select((x, i) => new { Val = x, Idx = (int?)i })
                        .Where(x => chars.IndexOf(x.Val) == -1)
                        .Select(x => x.Idx)
                        .FirstOrDefault();

int? lastNotOf = source.Select((x, i) => new { Val = x, Idx = (int?)i })
                       .Where(x => chars.IndexOf(x.Val) == -1)
                       .Select(x => x.Idx)
                       .LastOrDefault();
```

Or, if you prefer some non-LINQ extension methods. These should have slightly better performance, especially for `FindLastNotOf`:

```
int? firstNotOf = source.FindFirstNotOf(chars);
int? lastNotof = source.FindLastNotOf(chars);

// ...

public static int? FindFirstNotOf(this string source, string chars)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (chars == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("chars");
    if (source.Length == 0) return null;
    if (chars.Length == 0) return 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        if (chars.IndexOf(source[i]) == -1) return i;
    }
    return null;
}

public static int? FindLastNotOf(this string source, string chars)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (chars == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("chars");
    if (source.Length == 0) return null;
    if (chars.Length == 0) return source.Length - 1;

    for (int i = source.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (chars.IndexOf(source[i]) == -1) return i;
    }
    return null;
}
```

(It's possible that you *might* get better performance -- in both the LINQ and non-LINQ versions -- if you convert `chars` to a `HashSet<char>`, or maybe even a plain `char[]` array. You'd need to benchmark to find out, though any difference is likely to be negligible unless `chars` gets pretty big.)

Comment: Nice work, but who in their right mind finds any of that acceptable over a library or API routine? Looks like a MS fail.

Answer (score 4):

If the use of LINQ is acceptable, you can call the [First()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050.aspx) and [Last()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549138.aspx) methods with the appropriate predicate.

For instance, if you want the first and last characters that aren't vowels:

```
string vowels = "aeiouy";
char first = yourString.First(ch => vowels.IndexOf(ch) < 0);
char last = yourString.Last(ch => vowels.IndexOf(ch) < 0);
```

**EDIT:** The above will return the characters, not their indexes. In order to do that, you can project the indexes using the [Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) method, but things will get hairy since we need to return `-1` if no character matches:

```
int firstIndex = (yourString.Select(
        (ch, i) => new { Character = ch, Index = i }
    ).First(obj => vowels.IndexOf(obj.Character) < 0)
    ?? new { Character = '\0', Index = -1 }).Index;

int lastIndex = (yourString.Select(
        (ch, i) => new { Character = ch, Index = i }
    ).Last(obj => vowels.IndexOf(obj.Character) < 0)
    ?? new { Character = '\0', Index = -1 }).Index;
```

Alternatively, here's a less complicated solution based on @abatishchev's answer:

```
string vowels = "aeiouy";
int firstIndex = yourString.IndexOf(yourString.First(
    ch => vowels.IndexOf(ch) < 0));
int lastIndex = yourString.LastIndexOf(yourString.Last(
    ch => vowels.IndexOf(ch) < 0));
```

Comment: not exactly: `find_first_not_of` returns the position, not the character.

Comment: I think that LINQ overcomplicates things. And this solution is very ineffective. We are creating lot's of temporary objects of anonymous type along with iterators. Writing method that does simple for loop will be better.

Comment: You probably want to use LastOrDefault and FrstOrDefaut extension methods to supress exception throwing. Or I am missing something?

Comment: @Dmitry, since I'm using anonymous types, those methods would return `null` and the subsequent access to the `Index` property would fail. Since I wanted to return `-1` in that context, I had to create an explicit instance of the anonymous type with `Index` set to `-1`. I agree that's getting out of hand, though :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Regex solution.

```
string testString = "oueytestie";
var matchFirstNotOf = Regex.Match(testString, @"[^aeiouy]");
int firstNotOf = matchFirstNotOf.Success ? matchFirstNotOf.Index : -1;
var matchLastNotOf = Regex.Match(testString, @"[^aeiouy]", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
int lastNotOf = matchLastNotOf.Success ? matchLastNotOf.Index : -1;
```